# how to contact a user

Tags: support

Is there a way of sending a message to a particular user?

The only way I can see is to tag them in a question. This is good if you are wanting the discussion to be general but would not always be appropriate.

Mick

Answer (score 2):

As noted at MSE, *[How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537)*, the most reliable method is to create a chat room and use @handle to invite the other community member to it. The room is not private—others will be able to read the contents—but if privacy is a must you could at least use it to exchange other contact information.

TPTB have [shown no interest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431) in any private messaging capabilities for Stack Exchange users.